Copying files from one directory to another
I have a directory containing hundreds of jpg files and want to copy certain files to another directory at once. Is there a way to do this?
I was copying one by one and it is taking too much time. Is there any code by which I can copy the files to another directory based on the list of files.

It will take you a long time to make a list of these files for the script
Hold down the Ctrl key on the keyboard, select all the necessary files and copy them

You can just use the command in cmd (xcopy "directory path (that u want to copy)" "directory path (that u want to export to)"

In windows file explorer and search *jpg or whatever file format you want to select and then copy-paste to desired location.
